# Where JSON data

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I want done where date now with dates that there are in database table as JSON in offset 2 (like: `2011/10/30` = `date now` and `Etc.`), in my try output num rows is `0`. how can done it?

My column in table:

[image]

```
$today = date("Y/m/d"); // This is 2011/10/30
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE new_date LIKE $today");
echo $query->num_rows(); // This output is "0"
```

Comment: I'm sorry :)). do you can help me?

Comment: In the database you've got "2011\/10\/29" as your format, but you're using "2011/10/29" as your value for '$today'.  Try 2 things: a) put quotes around $today: "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `new_date` LIKE '$today'" and b) change your date to "2011\/10\/29" formatting and try again?

Comment: Hi JimBo - try my answer below - I forgot the %% delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE new_date LIKE '".$today."'");
```

Comment: No, still output num_rows is "0"

Comment: how is the 'new_date' formated? my date is like '2011-10-30', maybe you have to change the $today variable

Comment: is it an enum? and is it a V or \ and / ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$today = date("Y/m/d"); // This is 2011/10/30
$today = str_replace("/",'\/',$today); // match your db format in json

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `new_date` LIKE '%$today%'";
echo $sql.'<br />'; // Copy this line below so we can see your output

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `new_date` LIKE '%$today%'");
echo $query->num_rows();
```

Following from the comments above.

Comment: Do you get an SQL error message or just no results?  Also, can you echo out the exact $query string it produces:  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `new_date` LIKE '%$today"'".  Can you echo out and update what that gives you before you use it on the ->db->query() line?

Comment: just it no results, my output with print_r for query is as: http://pastebin.com/XyEveZsa

Comment: Hi, can you print out the query 'string' not the query object? e.g.: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `new_date` LIKE '%2011\/10\/30%' so we can see what it's asking for?

Comment: Sorry :) Don't use $query or print_r($query) or var_dump($query). Do this: $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `new_date` LIKE '%$today%'"; echo $sql;  Copy that $sql output back to here please?

Comment: i use codeigniter. output it is as: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `new_date` LIKE '%2011\/10\/30%'